# Hypernym of 'deposit' and 'withdraw'

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, phrase-requests, hypernyms

I am looking for a hypernym of *to deposit* and *to withdraw* (money to and from a bank account).

I thought about several options like "to perform a financial transaction", however I need something more concise and short.

Comment: A [compound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_%28linguistics%29) of *deposit* and *withdraw* would be *deposit-withdraw*. What you are looking for is a [hypernym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy).

Comment: you could use 'swap'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first hypernym I thought of was *transaction*, which can be a hypernym for *deposit* and *withdrawal*.

You're looking for a verb, though, not a noun. That being the case, you could use the verb [***transact***](http://www.wordnik.com/words/transact). Wiktionary says:

> **transact** (*v.*)
>    1. To do, carry through, conduct or perform some action.
>    2. To carry over, hand over or transfer something.
>    3. To conduct business.
>    4. To exchange or trade, as of ideas, money, goods, etc.

Answer (score 16):

*Transfer* can be used as a noun or verb to refer to deposits and withdrawals.

Comment: Agreed.  This immediately came to mind when reading the question title.

Comment: At least in typical banking terms, `transfer` generally means moving money from one account to another account, and wouldn't generally include, say, depositing or withdrawing cash.  I'd go with `transact` to be the most inclusive.

Answer (score 8):

Use transfer. This goes both ways.

> I transferred money to my account.
>
> I transferred money from my account.